How do I exclude basic Java functionality from layered architecture tests in ArchUnit?
I have written up the following test for my clean architecture. I still have a lot of violations like java.util functionality. Can I somehow exclude them from the LayeredArchitecture ArchUnit concept?
@Test
void layeredArchitectureTest() {
    Architectures.layeredArchitecture().consideringAllDependencies()
            .layer("Presentation").definedBy(PACKAGE_PREFIX + ".presentation..")
            .layer("Service").definedBy(PACKAGE_PREFIX + ".service..")
            .layer("Domain").definedBy(PACKAGE_PREFIX + ".domain..")
            .layer("Infrastructure").definedBy(PACKAGE_PREFIX + ".infrastructure..")
            .whereLayer("Presentation").mayOnlyAccessLayers("Service", "Domain", "Infrastructure")
            .whereLayer("Infrastructure").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("Service", "Domain", "Presentation")
            .whereLayer("Service").mayOnlyAccessLayers("Domain", "Infrastructure")
            .whereLayer("Domain").mayNotAccessAnyLayer()
            .check(classes);
}


Your question does not specify what "a lot of violations like java.util functionality" actually means (What do you get? What do you want?), but you may find the following methods helpful:

layeredArchitecture().consideringOnlyDependenciesInLayers():

consider only dependencies between the layers. All dependencies that either have an origin or a target outside any defined layer will be ignored. This provides a high level of convenience to eliminate false positives (e.g. dependencies on Object), but also introduces some danger to overlook corner cases that might conceal some unwanted dependencies.

or more specifically:

layeredArchitecture().consideringOnlyDependenciesInAnyPackage(String packageIdentifier, String... furtherPackageIdentifiers)

consider only dependencies from/to certain packages, e.g. the app root. All dependencies that either have an origin or a target outside these packages will be ignored. When set to the root package(s) of the application under test this offers a good balance between eliminating false positives (like dependencies to Object) and preventing unexpected corner cases that conceal some existing violations



or more specifically:

ignoreDependency(Class origin, Class target)

Configures the rule to ignore any violation from a specific origin class to a specific target class.

or more generally:

ignoreDependency(DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> origin, DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> target)

allows specifying origin and target by freely defined predicates. Any dependency where the Dependency.getOriginClass() matches the origin predicate and the Dependency.getTargetClass() matches the target predicate will be ignored.



